# Order of events in hibernation

Tags: physiology, homework

> Arrange this in sequence :
>
> i. Heat loss exceeds heat production.
>
> ii.As body temperature falls, heat loss decreases.
>
> iii.Body temperature equals environmental temperature.
>
> iv.Metabolic activities fall to the basal level.

I am confused between i,iii,ii,iv and iv,i,ii,iii.

Comment: @satwik you have answered my question. Just for the sake of our question to answer ratio why don't you " answer " it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the order `i,ii,iii` should be correct, since the fall in temperature occurs after the heat loss exceeds production and will continue only till the temperature equals the ambient temperature. `iv` is the reason for `i`. Hence `iv,i,ii,iii` sounds pretty convincing to me.

With `i,iii,ii,iv` , the main problem is that there can not be any appreciable fall in temperature `ii` after the temperature equals the environmental temperature `iii`. And `iv` seems more probably to be the reason for `i` rather than the reverse